# how to delete all the contents of a table and how to see the database in Eclipse or in Android Emulator

Tags: android

I made a database in android Application name `MgilePPR`

in which I created a table named Provider(`s_no,id,description`)

Table has created successfully and **4 rows are inserted** in it

**but every time i run my application it increases the row by +4**

so I have two questions

1. How do i empty a table before inserting
   records?
2. How do i see my database and table
   content in Eclipse or in Android
   emulator?

thanks for the replys in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. How to remove everything: execute SQL command `DELETE FROM Provider`.
2. How to view your database contents: this is described in developer's guide - [Examining databases from a remote shell](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite). Basically you open command line, type `adb shell`, then enter command like `sqlite3 /data/data/com.example.google.rss.rssexample/databases/rssitems.db` (substitute `com.example.google.rss.rssexample` with your application package). Then you can enter commands for sqlite. If you want to look at the contents of your database, just enter `.dump`.

**One thing I've noticed:** on emulator two files are actually created in databases folder, one is with extension .db and the other one without anything. So if you open db file and it contains nothing, try opening the other one.

Comment: i have a statment db.getPath(); and it return the data/data/mypackage/databases/table                                              but in the file explorer i only get upto path data/data/  now mypackage is not listed, so what should i do

Comment: Is `mypackage` really the name of your package? I advise you to name it in the usual three-word format (org.something.myapp, for example), there could be problems with one-word packages.

Answer (score 1):

hello I Think are writing code in onCreate() method and this will call each and every time as you run the activity.

You have to make a separate Function for that and you have to call when you want to insert data

and you want to see the contents of the table so 
open DDMS=>File Explorer=>data=>data=>package name of your application=>databases

now on right side there is option for push the file to your computer so save the file to your computer

now if you are using Mozilla then install Add-ons for SQLite manager or you can download sqlite query browser

then open your database file into that software

you can then access that database

Comment: i have a statment db.getPath(); and it return the data/data/mypackage/databases/table                                              but in the file explorer i only get upto path data/data/  now mypackage is not listed, so what should i do

Answer (score 1):

go to terminal and do like this

```
cd <platforms tools>
./adb shell
cd data
cd data
```

now you want to see your packages type `ls`

you can able to see your workspace packages

now type `cd <your package name>`
then

```
cd databases
sqlite3 <your database name>
```

now your can enter the sqlite database.
you want to see your tables
use `.tables`

`note:`your emulator should be on running mode.